# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, exception, integer

```
List<Integer> P = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(p)); // Copies array p into Arraylist P
P.sort(null);
List<Integer> kk = new ArrayList();
kk.set(0, P.get(0)+k); //Exception generated on this line
```

I do not know why I'm unable to set it that way. Can anyone please help me on this?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `p` here?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - ideally one which doesn't have two variables differing only by case, too...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, The other part of the program doesn't really matter much;
@ Rohit Jain, p is an array.

Comment: It *absolutely* does - what you've given us here isn't enough to reproduce the problem. I strongly suspect that Eran has the right idea here, and `p` is an `int[]`... which should give you a warning, but given your third line, it looks like you're ignoring warnings anyway. (Hint: stop doing that.)

Comment: @AshishPatil: An array of what kind? There's a big difference between `int[]` and `Integer[]` here. Rather than drip-feeding information, *please* provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem next time.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, I should be more clear when asking questions. I apologise for my arrogance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `p` is a primitive array `int[]`, `Arrays.asList(p)` would return a List whose single element is an `int[]`. That would explain why `P.get(0)` can't be cast to an Integer.

Change `p` to `Integer[]`, and `Arrays.asList()` would generate the List you desire.

It would also allow you to change this line :

```
List<Integer> P = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(p));
```

to

```
List<Integer> P = Arrays.asList(p);
```

You should avoid assigning a raw type to a generic type. This way you'd get a compilation error instead of a runtime error when you assign a List of the wrong type to `P` (which is easier to find and fix).